# SQL check if row value in one column is in another column that is a list of strings

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am pulling from a table that looks something like this:

| Name | List |
| --- | --- |
| John | 'John,Mary,Fred' |
| Mary | 'Jack, John' |

I need to pull only the rows where the value in the Name column is in the comma-separated list of names in the List column. In the example above, it would return just the first row. How can I do this using SQL (AWS Redshift version)?

Comment: I think you should be able to make [`REGEXP_INSTR()`](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_INSTR.html) work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This work?

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE list LIKE '%'||name||'%'
```

This has a hazard that 'jon' will match 'jonas'.  You can fix this will a bit extra conditions.  Also do you need this to be case insensitive? Then use ILIKE

If you need to match complete names you need to cover the 4 cases of how a name can show up in a list - first in list, middle of list, end of list, or all of the list.  Like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE list LIKE name||',%' 
   OR list LIKE '%,'||name||',%' 
   OR list LIKE '%,'||name
   OR list LIKE name
```

Comment: I can't have things like 'jon' matching 'jonas', it has to be exclusive. What extra conditions can be used, and are they easy to generalize?